# Set Finish Project Column via API

Tags: smartsheet-api

When I attempt to set the Finish column on a row in a sheet via the SmartSheet API, I get the following message:

```
{
    "errorCode": 1080,
    "message": "End Dates on dependency-enabled sheets cannot be created/updated. Please update either the Duration or Start Date column.",
    "refId": "19ufon4xzsn7y",
    "detail": {
        "index": 0,
        "rowId": 4987804240111492
    }
}
```

If I want to clear the project dates for a specific row I can set the Duration and Start columns to null, but the Finish date remains. See https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#update-rows

What is the programmatic way to clear the project dates, including Finish, for a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to programmatically update `Finish` date whenever ***dependencies are enabled*** for the sheet. Note, this is the sheet setting (in the Smartsheet UI) that specifies dependencies are enabled for a sheet:

[image]

If I ***manually*** uncheck this box and save the change via the Smartsheet UI, then I'm subsequently able to successfully update `Finish` dates via the API. Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to *disable dependencies for the sheet* via API (i.e., the programmatic equivalent of unchecking this box). I tried doing so, but received an error indicating that you cannot set the `dependenciesEnabled` property via API.

**REQUEST:**

```
PUT /sheet/{sheetId)
{
   "dependenciesEnabled": false
}
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
{
    "errorCode": 1032,
    "message": "The attribute(s) sheet.dependenciesEnabled are not allowed for this operation.",
    "refId": "10pl3li0rs9b"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kim. Additionally, when disabling dependencies in the sheet, the Duration column becomes a normal Text/Number field and no longer supports duration values, such as “10d”, “2w”, etc.

Comment: @Rick - thanks for pointing this out. The behavior you've described is consistent with what I'd expect. "Dependencies Enabled" is what makes a sheet a "project" sheet (i.e., tells Smartsheet to treat the data like a project plan, with dependencies, durations, start dates, end dates, etc.). If dependencies is disabled, Smartsheet will no longer treat the data like a project plan, so any *special* column types and auto-calculations that happen for those special columns in a project sheet will no longer be present.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update the Finish Date programmatically on a dependency enabled sheet via the API.

In order to do so I had to pass the date string in [their specified format](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/API-Basics/Dates-and-Times), and populate the `strict` property = `true` on both of the `Start Date` and `Duration` [cell objects](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/rows#operation/rows-addToSheet).

Using C#, you can get the date string formatted correctly using this
code: `startDate.ToString("O")`